# Problems with receiving input from JButton

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, actionlistener

This is my Black Jack program, it's still a WIP but the program will run. The problem is that clicking the JButton hit will not .setText to the new value, stored in the JLabel total.  Someone please help!

```
import java.awt.Color;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.text.*;
import java.awt.Font.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

public class A3_Poltoranos_Max implements ActionListener{

  int playerCard1 = (int)(Math.random() * 11) * 1 + 1;
  int playerCard2 = (int)(Math.random() * 11) * 1 + 1;
  int totalScore = playerCard1 + playerCard1;``

  JPanel background;
  JLabel total, totalTitle;
  JButton hit, stand;

  public JPanel createContentPane(){
    JPanel totalGUI = new JPanel();    
    totalGUI.setLayout(null);

    JPanel background = new JPanel();
    Color feltGreen = new Color(27, 154, 25);
    background.setLayout(null);
    background.setBackground(feltGreen);
    background.setLocation(0, 0);
    background.setSize(800,600);
    totalGUI.add(background);

    JLabel totalTitle = new JLabel("Your total:");

    totalTitle.setLocation(150, 50);
    totalTitle.setSize(100, 40);
    totalTitle.setHorizontalAlignment(0);
    background.add(totalTitle);

    JLabel total = new JLabel(""+totalScore);

    total.setLocation(150, 200);
    total.setSize(100, 40);
    total.setHorizontalAlignment(0);
    background.add(total);

    JButton hit = new JButton("Hit!");
    hit.setLocation(50, 450);
    hit.setSize(100, 30);
    hit.addActionListener(this);
    background.add(hit);

    JButton stand = new JButton("Stand!");
    stand.setLocation(250, 450);
    stand.setSize(100, 30);
    stand.addActionListener(this);
    background.add(stand);

    totalGUI.setOpaque(true); 
    return totalGUI;  
  }
  @Override
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if(e.getSource() == hit)
        {
            playerCard2 = (int)(Math.random() * 11) * 1 + 1;
            totalScore = totalScore + playerCard2;
            total.setText(""+totalScore);
        }
        else if(e.getSource() == stand)
        {            
            total.setText(""+totalScore);
        }
    }

  private static void createWindow() {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Black Jack V 0.1"); 
    A3_Poltoranos_Max demo = new A3_Poltoranos_Max();
    frame.setContentPane(demo.createContentPane());

    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setSize(800, 600);
    frame.setVisible(true); 
  }
  public static void main(String[] args) { 
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
      public void run() {
    createWindow();

      }
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You store the button in a local var "hit" instead of the object var "hit" - this is why the test

```
if(e.getSource() == hit)
```

will always fail (hit is null).

Do not declare a new variable and the code should work:

```
hit = new JButton("Hit!");
```

instead of

```
JButton hit = new JButton("Hit!");
```

(same of course applies to the other buttons, labels and the panel, too.)

Comment: Yeah, I just realized you could do that

Answer (score 1):

Stefan's answer is correct.

Another thing you can do is put the action listener on the button itself:

```
hit.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    playerCard2 = (int)(Math.random() * 11) * 1 + 1;
    totalScore = totalScore + playerCard2;
    total.setText(""+totalScore);
  }
});
```

If you do this for the Stand button as well, you can remove the ActionListener interface from your class.

This does a few things:

1. It makes it more clear about what button is doing what activity
2. It removes the need for a class-scope JButton definition - now, you *can* keep `JButton hit = new JButton("Hit!");` and remove the class-level variable
3. It's a bit more object-oriented, as opposed to having a set of `if` statements in a single actionPerformed() method